# Retrieve specified column records with attribute names

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, database

I have a model with some attributes.

If I display all records in JSON format

```
respond_with(Group.all)
```

It shows all records with corresponding attribute names. I want to display all records except some column records. So, I used

```
@groupDetails = Group.pluck(:id,:name,:created_at)
respond_with(@groupDetails)
```

It shows all specified attribute records, but I want all these records with corresponding attribute names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [select method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select):

```
Group.select(:id,:name,:created_at)
```